# Misunderstanding about implementaion of generic interface in another interface

Tags: java, generics

I try to create interface that implements another generic interface:

```
public interface MinMax implements Comparable<T> {
}
```

But on `T` I get error cannot resolve symbol `T`.

So I tried this syntax:

```
public interface MinMax <T extends Comparable> {    
}
```

It's worked I don't get any errors on the syntax above.

I can't understand why should I use extends and not implements while comparable is interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first snippet you try to use the generic type variable `T` without first declaring it. You also can't say that an interface `implements` another interface (only a class can implement an interface). Instead, an interface can extend another interface.

You can declare it with:

```
public interface MinMax<T> extends Comparable<T> {

}
```

This means that interface `MinMax` has a generic type parameter called `T` and the interface extends the `Comparable<T>` interface (which means any implementation of thie `MinMax` interface would have to implement the `public int compareTo(T o);` method).

You second snippet

```
public interface MinMax <T extends Comparable> {

}
```

has a different meaning. Here `MinMax` also have a generic type parameter named `T`, but you require that `T` implements `Comparable` (note that when used in a generic type bound, the keyword `extends` can mean either extends a class or implements an interface), which means `MinMax` itself does not extend the `Comparable` interface.

One last thing, the second snippet makes more sense as

```
public interface MinMax <T extends Comparable<T>> {

}
```

since you don't want to use the raw `Comparable` interface. You want to specify which type of objects you are comparing with your `Comparable`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: because that `T` must come from **somewhere**!

You need:

```
public interface MinMax<T> extends Comparable<T> {
}
```

for example. And the real answer is: don't go for **trial and error**. You have to **learn** this concept. Start reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for example. Or if you are an experienced programmer and want to go hardcore - turn [there](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

But don't think that trial and error is an efficient strategy to understand a completely new concept.

Then you would also understand the difference:

```
public interface MinMax<T> implements Comparable<T> {
```

Allows for *any* type to be used with this interface later on. Whereas

```
public interface MinMax <T extends Comparable>
```

says that MinMax allows for any type T that implements the Comparable interface.

And of course - the comment is fully correct: interfaces **extend** each other, they do not **implement**.

Comment: + also an interface can not *implement* another interface.

Comment: Good observation. I overlooked that. Fixed now.